# Variable not found `$navbarColor`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I get this error while trying to import a variable into my `.scss` file in Ruby on Rails

```
Error: Undefined variable: "$navbarColor".
        on line 2:17 of app/assets/stylesheets/partials/layout/navigation.scss
>>     background: $navbarColor !important;
   ----------------^
```

My `navigation.scss` file looks like this

```
.navbar-default, .navbar-toggle:focus, .collapsed, button.navbar-toggle {
    background: $navbarColor !important;
    border: none;
    a {
      color: white !important;
    }
}
```

My `variables.scss` file where I store all the variables looks like this
`$navbarColor: #323738;`

My `application.scss` file looks like this

```
//  Bootstrap (version 5 rendered using the bs5 engine)
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";


 // Variables
 @import "./base/variables";

 // Partials - main SCSS Files
 @import "partials/layout/*";
```

The tree structure of the directory for stylesheets is

```
app
├───assets
│   ├───config
│   │       manifest.js
│   │
│   ├───images
│   │       .keep
│   │
│   └───stylesheets
│       │   application.scss
│       │   pages.scss
│       │
│       ├───base
│       │       variables.scss
│       │
│       └───partials
│           └───layout
│                   navigation.scss
```

This throws an error stating that `$navbarColor` is not defined in addition to another error. Both of them are shown below
[image]
Error 1

[image]
Error 2

(The errors shown here are improved by the `better_errors` gem)

But when I add the gem `binding_of_caller` the Error 1 vanishes but still the latter persists. But the error still is the absence of definition of `$navbarColor` according to it. I added this gem since it was given as a tip in the `better_errors` as shown in the images.

Despite the export of the variable in `application.scss`, it shows this error. But when I add the following line in the `navigation.scss`, the error vanishes but the styles are not exported.

```
@import '../../base/variables';
```

Could anyone please say why this happened?

Comment: Where did you initialized $navbarColor value ?

Comment: `variables.scss` I have mentioned this in the question haven't I?

Comment: Sorry, I missed it

Answer (score 0):

It's because you removed these lines from `application.scss`:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

You have to import newly created files in `application.scss`:

```
// ...default comments

// Bootstrap
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

// Variables
@import "base/variables";

// Partials - main css files
@import "partials/layout/*";
```